# Growing up/ From a young age

Tags: meaning-in-context, colloquial-language

*"**From a young age** we aren't taught to help others. **Growing up we are** taught
to play it safe and avoid risk at all cost."*

1. Are the sentences correct? I'm not sure about 'from a young age' and 'growing up we are.'
2. I know that any native or nan-native speaker would easily understand what this sentence mean. But does it sound natural?

Comment: Both expressions are common. You would require a comma after **Growing up,** and the more common phrase is **at all costs** in the plural. https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=at+all+cost%2Cat+all+costs&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cat%20all%20cost%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cat%20all%20costs%3B%2Cc0

Answer (score 1):

> From a young age, we aren't taught to help others. Growing up, we are taught to avoid any risks.

The sentence beginnings are correct. There are a few commas, and the “play it safe” part is defined two times, so we lower it to one definition and that deletes the mentioned part.

Comment: It was an IELTS question. The question was whether humans have to be taught to to help others or are they naturally inclined to help others. Does it make sense now?